# How can i connect my Vms connect to each other over virtual private network in azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, cloud, azure-networking

How can i connect my Vms connect to each other  over virtual private network in azure?  should i have to do extra configutaion of just from one vm if i use private ip and port of other vm can i access ?
while creating vm it do not show the virtual network of other vm.

so tell me if i can communicate this virtual private networks .

Answer (score 2):

If the VMs are connected to the same virtual network, nothing else is required for them to talk to each other; they are by definition already connected (unless you have NSGs blocking traffic between them); this also applies to different subnets in the same VNet.

If the VMs are connected to different VNets, you need to set up a [virtual network peering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) to connect the two VNets.

If you are not shown the option to connect a VM to a specific VNet when creating it, the reason usually is that the VM and the VNet are in different Azure regions; a VM can only be connected to a VNet in the same region.